# Add references to a project template programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project-template

I'm doing a project Template. there is some custom parameters ( The services and attributes that he will be using during the implementation of the project ). Each service needs a specific reference. So depending on the custom parameters, I prepare a list that contains the paths of the needed assemblies. How can I add them to the project ?! I tried the following code but no result.`

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(@"path").Result;
            var projects = solution.Projects;
            foreach (EnvDTE.Project proj in solution.Projects)
            {
                if (proj.Name == projectName)
                {
                    VSLangProj.VSProject vsproj = (VSLangProj.VSProject)proj.Object;
                    foreach (string dll in Wizard.View.View.refs)
                    {
                        vsproj.References.Add(dll);
                    }
                }
            }`
```